# Grails render template where?

Tags: grails

Up until now I have rendered my templates after formRemote submissions where I can identify which div to update as an attribute on the formRemote markup, but what if I am wanting to render a template which isn't a result of a formRemote submission? In that case, how can I send a model and tell the gsp where I want it rendered? I take it the model will be sent something like:

```
render(model: [recordToEdit: recordToEdit])
```

or simply

```
[recordToEdit: recordToEdit]
```

but how to tell the GSP where I want the bits and pieces of the model to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
<g:render template="blah" model="['recordToEdit':recordToEdit]" />
```

And the send the model along from the parent action?

Comment: But how to tell the GSP which div or area to render it into? Kind of like the equivalent of the "update=blah" attribute of formRemote.

Comment: You would add this code directly to your GSP which would allow you to put it where it needs to go.